# HubL: How to programmatically get the total number of items of your blog?

Tags: jinja2, template-engine, hubspot

I'm using HubSpot's markup language called HubL. I want to get the total number of the blog's posts for pagination purposes.

I'm using the "Variables in blog post, and blog listing templates" to do this from [here](http://designers.hubspot.com/docs/markup/supported-variables). This is how far I've got:

```
{% if next_page_num %}
     {{ last_page_num + 1 }} of {{ contents|length - 1 }}
{% endif%}
```

Unfortunately, "the contents|length" part of the code is only counting the number of blog posts you've specified on the page (in my case only 12 blog posts are displayed) and I don't know how to get the overall total.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with this variable:

```
{{ blog_total_post_count() }}
```

I found the answer here: (http://inbound.org/question/view/has-anyone-added-numeric-pagination-to-a-cos-blog).